# how to pass parameter value from anchor tag to jquery modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below code,

```
    <a href="#small" data-toggle="modal" data-id="id1333">  
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/mthumb.jpg" /></a>

     <div id="small" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" data-replace="true">
         <div class="modal-body">
             <table>
            <tr>        <td>                 
                         <iframe id="videoid" width="620" height="390" ></iframe>
                 </td>
            <tr>    </table>
         </div> </div>
```

Here I want to pass data-id to modal window. This data-id is used by frame src attribute.
Please suggest on how I can pass/use the parameter in iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id = $('a[href="#small"]').data('id');
    $('#videoid').attr('src', id);
});
```

You can get `data-id` with `data` and put inside the attribute `src` of your iframe.
This code is launched when the page is loaded, but if you want to launch when click the link button you need to create an event `click` on your link

Answer (score 0):

As the href and modal is on the same page. You can use the `$("element").data("modal").isShown  == true`. Then in that if condition you can get the `.data("id")` of the `<a>` and assign it to the frame `src` attr by doing this: